# What is Aussie Native Potting Mix made of?

Tags: native

My question is about Australian Native potting mix. Most of the species of Aussie natives do **NOT** need high nutrient soil but it needs only the low phosphorus fertiliser + the normal garden soil.

I have seen such potting mixes available in nursery stores but that's very expensive considering the size of potting mix bag vs price. Hence I was thinking to make my own.

If I just use normal garden soil and put some chicken pellet manured fertiliser then does it mean that it satisfies the requirements mentioned (low phosphorus fertiliser + the normal garden soil)?

Thank you for your help...

Comment: in Australia, premium potting mix has a standard which includes fertiliser. So buy cheap potting  mix with no fertiliser in it. Chicken manure is perhaps a bit rich....not sure.